# Rails Convert yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ To date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Following is my query where I am fetching order wise payments on latest first basis.

I wish to fetch `OrderPayment` `created_at` here.

If I write `<%= OrderPayment.last.created_at%>` I get `2019-06-28 16:31:12 +053` which is a date, and I'm currently using `<%= order_payment["created_at"]%>` where I get `2019-06-28T11:01:12.686086` which is a string.

Why am I getting such a weird representation?

```
@order_payments = OrderPayment.select("order_id, json_agg(order_payments.* order by order_payments.created_at desc) as details").includes(order:).order("order_id desc").group(:order_id)

#iterating @orderpayments for listing
<% @order_payments.each do |order_detail| %>
 <%details = order_detail.details%>
  <%=order_payment["created_at"]%>
<%end%>
```

if i do `<%= Time.at(DateTime.parse(order_payment["created_at"])).strftime("%d-%m-%y %I:%M %p")%>` i get output like OrderPayment.last.created_at but i want to know whats the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your situation database and your rail environment time zones are different.
and its returning db value as it is with timezone
you should try **`Time.zone.parse(//your query//)`**
It will return time and date with current time zone.